# XML serialization - collection of multiple types

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I want to put inside `Submenu` two different tags: `Item` and `Separator` and then parse XML document with XmlSerializer. I can do it when `Submenu` contains only `Item` sequence.

Exemplary XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Navigation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">
  <Menu Name="Main">
    <Item Caption="File">
      <Submenu>
        <Item Caption="New" Command="." />
        <Item Caption="Open" Command="." />
        <Separator />
        <Item Caption="Exit" Command="." />
      </Submenu>
    </Item>
  </Menu>
</Navigation>
```

And (not) working C# code:

```cs
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Navigation", IsNullable = false)]
public class Navigation
{
    [XmlElement("Menu")]
    public List<Menu> MenuCollection { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Menu", IsNullable = false)]
public class Menu
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Item", IsNullable = false)]
public class Item
{

    [XmlAttribute("Caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Command")]
    public string Command { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Submenu", IsNullable = true)]
    public Menu Submenu { get; set; }
}
```

`Menu.Items` should contains Items and Separators. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although conceptually a menu item and a separator are two different things, it's easiest to think of them both as menu items. Add a new property to your `Menu` class:

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsSeparator { get; set; }
```

This way, `Menu.Items` need only ever contain `Items`. Your XML will end up with elements such as

```
    <Item IsSeparator="true" />
```